# Как на локальном сервере разработки django использовать вместо sqlite базу данных mysql?

Tags: django

Ищу в интернете, пока не могу нигде найти какое-нибудь руководство

Comment: Очень странно вы искали, первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу «django mysql» https://www.delftstack.com/ru/howto/django/django-mysqldb/

Comment: спасибо, это понятно. "Прежде чем приступить к настройке подключения, убедитесь, что в вашей системе настроен MySQL. Убедитесь, что у вас есть учетная запись и созданы базы данных, к которым вы хотите подключиться."  Вот это хотелось бы расшифровать. Что значит настроен  MySQL,, создана учетная запись и база?

Comment: Это уже читайте руководства по установке и настройке сервера MySQL, Django тут уже совершенно ни при чём. Опять же, по запросу в гугле «mysql руководство» выдаётся очень много всякой информации

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/ru/howto/django/django-mysqldb/ Это очень точная и понятная инструкция. Если вы находите ее сложной и непонятной то тогда посмотрите тутсы про базы данных, их типы и отличия. А вообще советую изучить докер и потом играться с базами данных. Удачи.